# Objective-C preferred way to define variables

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
    NSString *str = @"David Likes Going To The Park";
    NSString *separator = @" ";
    NSArray *strSplit = [str componentsSeparatedByString:separator];
    NSNumber *strSplitLength = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[strSplit count]];
    NSLog(@"Splitting STRING %@ on SEPARATOR %@ = %@ of LENGTH %@", str, separator, strSplit, strSplitLength);
```

Would this be considered acceptable code? Or should all the variables be defined at the top before usage, something like:

```
NSString *str, *separator;
NSNumber *strSplitLength;
NSArray *strSplit;
// rest of code
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference unless used earlier

Comment: It really depends on the usage. Defined on the top iff, they are needed at class level.

Comment: whatever way makes it more readable and maintainable (to most people including me, is the first way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part you did "`declaration cum definition`" in the second part you deferred the definition.

Memory for the object will be created once you define it. So there is no difference.